# How to prevent Gitlab from creating extra merge commit on branch merge

Tags: git, version-control, merge, gitlab

I use GitLab in my project. I'm exploring Merge Requests feature.

1. I created a `topic_branch` from `master`.
2. Made a bunch of commits on `topic_branch`.
3. Pushed `topic_branch` to remote.
4. Created a merge request on `master` to pull changes from `topic_branch`.
5. On accept merge in Gitlab, `master` pulled all the commits and also created a merge commit which is horrible to see duplication of code.

I should have created a squash of commits on branch and then created merge request. But still `master` would have two new commits, one from the branch and another one would be merge commit. I'm assuming, if I do this from command line i.e,

1. checkout `master`
2. merge `topic_branch` into `master`
3. commit / push `master`
   In this case, there would be only 1 commit on `master`.

How to achieve this from GitLab ?

Answer (score 49):

##### TL;DR

Your Project > Settings > General > Merge Request Settings > Fast-Forward Merge.

**Note**: in recent Gitlab versions the Merge Request Settings are not located under General anymore, they're directly located under Settings: Your Project > Settings > Merge Requests > Merge Method > Fast-Forward Merge.

Personally, I also prefer to do `squash commits` on every merge.

---

I think GitLab supports this now.

#### Steps

1. Go to your `project`
2. Navigate to project `settings` (Note: This is NOT the profile settings available on the top right)
3. Go to `General` tab.
4. Navigate to `Merge Request Settings` section
5. Choose `Fast-Forward Merge`.

[image]

Comment: PS: the `Fast-Forward` setting only supported in EE or CE(10.1+)

Comment: This fast forward option force us always to rebase source branch. Can we avoid that?

Comment: Is there a way to set this as a preference for all future projects?

Answer (score 2):

> I should have created a squash of commits on branch

With [GitLab 13.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/08/22/gitlab-13-3-released/#squash-commits-options) (August 2020), there is a new option which is interesting in your case:

> ### Squash Commits Options
>
> Squashing commits in Git is a great way to combine several commits into a single one.
> It’s great for grouping several commits, which by themselves may provide little historical value, into a single large commit before pushing upstream.
> Pushing a single commit allows for a more meaningful commit message, as well as ensuring the group of commits provides a “green” continuous integration pipeline.
>
> In GitLab 13.3 we are adding configurable defaults for squashing commits, allowing project maintainers to configure the option to suit their preferred workflow.
>
> Because changing squash configuration may introduce unwanted behavior, configuration has not been changed for new or existing projects. With 314 upvotes , this is one of the most highly requested improvements by the community and we hope it allows more users to use this powerful feature.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_3/create_source_code_configurable_defaults_for_squash_commits_option.png -- Squash Commits Options]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/squash_and_merge.html#squash-commits-options) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/17613).

Answer (score 1):

Well，as [the doc say](http://www.obsis.unb.br/gitlab/help/workflow/gitlab_flow.md#do-not-order-commits-with-rebase)：

> GitLab Enterprise Edition offers a way to rebase before merging a merge request. You can configure this per project basis by navigating to the project settings page and selecting Merge Requests Rebase checkbox.

basically Enterprise Edition is the key point，pay for rebase function.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/rebase_before_merge.html GitLab will always create merge commit to keep a way to revert the whole branch.

Comment: @CSchulz, we have some free Gitlab instance and Merge requests create merge commits even while rebasing. Maybe you mean EE has some "revert" button? You can revert merge commits from console and without need of --force.

Comment: Sorry I missed the detail about the rebase. I will delete this comment soon.

Comment: **Note:** The rebase before merge is an Enterprise Edition feature.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. checkout `master`
> 2. merge `topic_branch` into `master`
> 3. commit / push `master` In this case, there would be only 1 commit on `master`.

That is not true. You will have all the commits from `topic_branch` and a `Merge branch 'topic_branch'`commit in your master, **except** the case that no commits were added to your master branch since you branched off `topic_branch`. In this case, the default behaviour of `git merge` is to perform a [fast forward merge](https://wikileaks.org/ciav7p1/cms/files/git-ffwd.pdf). A fast forward merge merges your `topic_branch`es changes to master *without* a merge commit (see [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---ff) for further documentation).

However, when you create a merge request in GitLab, as the name says, you are requesting to merge your `topic_branch` into your code base. Per default, GitLab will always create a merge request, even if a fast forward merge is possible, to preserve the fact that the commits were developed on another branch in your history.

Now the good news: you can configure GitLab to perform fast-forward merges instead of creating merge commits: see [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/fast_forward_merge.html). It seems, however, that this is only possible in GitLab Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score -1):

**update** currently gitlab supports both rejecting non-fast-forward commits and squashing multiple commits of a merge request, so my comment below isn't that valid anymore

**original content**

If you don't want to have a merge commit, don't do a merge. That means do a rebase on target branch (master) and a push.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Manually yes, you can do all flows you need. But from GitLab's interface there doesn't appear to be a good solution to _not_ have an extra _Merge_ commit.

Comment: @k3liutZu it is up to user whether he wants or not to have a merge commit irrespectively of what gitlab thinks of that. The author of the question would obviously prefer not to have one (me to).